# Set element.style with an object of style properties

Tags: javascript, css, dom

Is there a way to do something like that:

```js
    var my_element= document.createElement("div");
    my_element.style={
      position:"absolute",
      background:"red",
      ...
    }
```

instead of:

```
my_element.style.position= "absolute";
my_element.style.background= "red";
```

Or

```
var my_properties={
      position:"absolute",
      background:"red",
      ...
}
for( var i in my_properties )
  my_element.style[i]= my_properties[i];
```

Comment: 2nd option should work

Comment: I know! Actually, I thought about that while writing the question. I'm still asking in the case that a better solution exists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it using `for...in`

```
var my_element= document.createElement("div");
var elemStyle = my_element.style;
var my_properties={
      position:"absolute",
      background:"red",
      ...
}
for(var prop in my_properties) {
  elemStyle[prop] = my_properties[prop];
}
```

Or you can `setAttribute` for style.

```
var elemstyle = my_element.getAttribute("style");
my_element.setAttribute(
   "style", elemstyle+"font-size: 100px; font-style: italic; color:#ff0000;");
```

Comment: For the second, it will overwrite existing styles of the element, but as I just created it, it is good for me

Comment: A semicolon before font-size would be safer. I try to edit your answer, but I had just 1 chacter to modify...